# tf.shape() returns a 2-d tensor instead of 1-d

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

In the tensorflow API `tf.shape`, it says

> This operation returns a 1-D integer tensor representing the shape of input.

However, when I call

```
features = {
    'k_mask': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
    'features': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
    'labels': tf.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.int64),
    'k_ids': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64)
}
parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
features_index = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_features['features'])
print(sess.run(tf.shape(features_index)))
```

I get the result of `[[59]]`, which is a 2-D integer tensor. The `feature_index` can be print as

```
[[ 6217  5882 17223 17235  6008  3580 17233  6038 16340  6116  5458  5747
   5957  5755 17238  5745  6030  6078  5786  4373  5888 16284  3574  3569
   5811  6117  5748 17228  5810  5833  5823  5885  5986  6034  5756  6105
   5832  6199  6087  5744  6037  5933  6095  5785 16290  6124  3559  5787
   6111  3570  6109 17322  3840  5962  3566 16950  6006  3584  6011]]
```

I thought this is a normal [1, 59] tensor. I try the following code:

```
v1 = tf.constant([[4,3,1,7]])
print(sess.run(v1)) # [[4 3 1 7]]
print(sess.run(tf.shape(v1))) # [1 4]
```

It looks as expected.

I want transform `feature_index` to shape of [59,1]. Would anyone knows why the return type is 2-d and how to convert the tensor?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved as below:

```
features_index = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_features['features'])
indices = tf.reshape(features_index, [tf.shape(features_index)[0], -1])
```

get `shape(indices) == [59,1]`